# Typography of Mixed Tensor Index Notation

Tags: formatting, tensors, index, subscript

How can one *properly and quickly* write a mixed "tensor" such as  $\Gamma{}_{1}{}^{2}{}_{3}$?

Shortcuts such as <kbd>esc</kbd> Gamma <kbd>esc</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>^</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>_</kbd> are prefered. I intendd to use this in an inline equation in a Mathematica Text cell.

Comment: I've seen Mathematica output looking like that, so I know it is possible. I just don't know how to properly type it.